# ValidationGroup doesn't "see" elements that are collapsable, i.e. made with some visible condition and resolves to valid when it's not in CxJS

Tags: cxjs

I tried to make a collapsable element using some visible condition. The thing is some of the elements inside that collapsable section need to satisfy certain conditions and therefore I use ValidationGroup to make sure everything is alright. Everything works fine until I collapse the section, and suddenly ValidationGroup doesn't seem to see the form inside the collapsed section and shows that it's valid.

```js
import { Button, HtmlElement, TextField, ValidationGroup } from "cx/widgets";

export const App = (
  <cx>
    <Button
      text="Collapse/Expand"
      onClick={(e, { store }) => store.toggle("visibleCondition")}
    />
    <ValidationGroup invalid-bind="invalid">
      <div visible-bind="visibleCondition">
        <TextField label="Label" required asterisk />
      </div>
    </ValidationGroup>
    // Form is invalid if required fields are still empty
    // but you can see here that you see this div below even though when you expand the section
   // you see that this field is still empty
    <div
      visible-expr="!{invalid}"
      text="This is visible if form is not invalid"
      style="margin-top:20px;"
    />
  </cx>
);
```

Here is the [fiddle link with the code written above](https://fiddle.cxjs.io/?f=NDI9A1ET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the visible condition on an element is not met, that element is removed from the DOM. Therefore the ValidationGroup does not see it, and cannot interact with it. In this case, you could control the visibility of an element with pure CSS.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<cx>
    <Button
      text="Collapse/Expand"
      onClick={(e, { store }) => store.toggle("visibleCondition")}
    />
    <ValidationGroup invalid-bind="invalid">
      <div class={{ hidden: bind("visibleCondition") }}>
        <TextField label="Label" value-bind="test" required asterisk />
      </div>
    </ValidationGroup>
    <div
      visible-expr="{invalid}"
      text="This is visible if form is not invalid"
      style="margin-top:20px;"
    />
</cx>
```

It ain't pretty, but it works.

Comment: "display:none": bind("visibleCondition") this does not work.. even though I imported it... 
import { bind } from "cx/ui";
maybe it's fiddle problem ?

Comment: Here is the edited version. You had a couple of mistakes, including opposite logic in the div that displays the message, and also, TextField needs value-bind in order to be validated.

Comment: My bad, the logic for that specific text is correct.